# Google PHP API Client fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode() not working

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-php-client

**Environment details**

*OS:* Ubuntu 20

*PHP version:* 7.3.33

*Package name and version:* api-client v2.12.1 / 2.10.0 / 2.9.2

**Steps to reproduce**

After redirection to `callback url` with `auth code` from google, I am trying to fetch the `access token` using auth code by calling `fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode('auth code')` but it gets stuck and nothing comes after. It basically returns a `request timeout` as no response is returned from Google even after 05 minutes.

**Code example**

```php
$client = new Google\Client;
$client->setApplicationName("CM");
$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secret.json');
if ($_GET['code']) {
    $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
    $client->setAccessToken($token);
    // Check to see if there was an error.
    if (array_key_exists('error', $token)) {
        throw new Exception(join(', ', $token));
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: where are you getting code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the issue was my ISP blocking the Google API URL. It stands resolved now.